# I need to convert C (or better) into RISC-V that https://venus.cs61c.org/ will accept

Tags: c, riscv

I have tried https://godbolt.org/ and all the different conversions to RISC-V but it still errors.

for example my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("test");
    
    
    return 0; 
}
```

converts to:

```
main:                                   # @main
        addi    sp, sp, -16
        sw      ra, 12(sp)                      # 4-byte Folded Spill
        sw      s0, 8(sp)                       # 4-byte Folded Spill
        addi    s0, sp, 16
        mv      a0, zero
        sw      a0, -16(s0)                     # 4-byte Folded Spill
        sw      a0, -12(s0)
        lui     a0, %hi(.L.str)
        addi    a0, a0, %lo(.L.str)
        call    printf
        lw      a0, -16(s0)                     # 4-byte Folded Reload
        lw      s0, 8(sp)                       # 4-byte Folded Reload
        lw      ra, 12(sp)                      # 4-byte Folded Reload
        addi    sp, sp, 16
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "test"
```

it gives error at "lui" because it expected 2 arguments but received 3. I tried organizing the code a bit by using .data section and .text section but still no work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `la $a0, .L.str` instead of your 2-instruction %hi,%lo combo.

Also, use `.string` instead of `.asciz`.

Comment: That does fix that issue. The other issuing being any function I use from the #include does not seem to be converted. So I would have to copy the source code for printf and paste it explicitly into the converter?